# Animating on left doesnt move element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-position

On hover, I want to move top picture to show picture under it. Left and Right values are changing in DOM, but visually picture doesn't move.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var left = $('#left').offset().left;
 var right = $('#right').offset().right;
 $("#left").hover(
  function(){
   $("#right #top").css({right:right}).animate({"right": "+=100px"},"slow");
  
  },
  function(){
   $("#right #top").css({right:right}).animate({"right": "-=100px"},"slow");
  });
 
 $("#right").hover(
  function(){
   $("#left #top").css({left:left}).animate({"left": "-=100px"},"slow");
  
  },
  function(){
   $("#left #top").css({left:left}).animate({"left": "+=100px"},"slow");
  });
});
```

```css
html,body,#wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#center{
 width: 800px;
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
}

img{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
}

#left{
 width:400px;
 float:left;
 position:absolute;
}

#right{
 width:400px;
 float:right;
}

#top{
 z-index:1;
}

#under{
   z-index:-1;
   float: none;
   height: auto;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css"> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="center">
    <div id="left">
     <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/p5mgljj5x/drums_left.jpg" id="top">
     <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/4vp56ei11/workout_left.jpg" id="under">
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/6ep4p4dz9/drums_right.jpg" id="under">
     <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/mzs5r1fph/workout_right.jpg" id="top">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 
 <footer>
 </footer>
</html>
```

I guess there is a problem with usage of position property in css?

And fiddle looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bjgydLvo/4/

Comment: You might be better trying to do this with CSS animation

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class your moving image and add the following CSS

```
.animate{
  left:0;
  transition:all .2s;
  position:relative;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#center').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.animate').css('left','-100%')
})
$('#center').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.animate').css('left','0')
})
```

Example
https://jsfiddle.net/8fbohssn/1/

If you want to hide the sliding image as it leaves just add `overflow:hidden;` to the parent container

Example
https://jsfiddle.net/8fbohssn/2/

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you! Is there an easy way to hide sliding image behind the div? So when it slides, it disappears behind "white background"?

Comment: Check the second example i supplied in the original answer

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you have multiple elements with the same id. IDs are unique identifiers - you might want to use classes instead.

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/bjgydLvo/8/), I removed `#top` and changed `under` from ID to class, as you are using it two times.

The animation works now. If this is not the desired result, please comment below.

Comment: Hi, your solution starts doing what I want it to do, its just that my remaining code is not good and it starts breaking DOM with adding 100 to left everytime I hover. Thank you for you help!